BIRT runtime 4.15 won't start in Tomcat 10
We're trying to upgrade from BIRT Report Viewer runtime 4.8 to the latest 4.15.
I downloaded the latest version of Tomcat 10 (10.1.23)
https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi
and downloaded the latest release of BIRT-runtime (birt-runtime-4.15.0-202403270652.zip)
https://download.eclipse.org/birt/updates/release/latest/
I am using java 17 version jdk17.0.8_8
I place the birt.war file in the webapps directory, startup tomcat and I get the following error message in localhost.[date].log. Just wondering if anyone else is getting the same error?
I figured maybe I'm missing a dependency I need to place in my tomcat/lib folder, but not really sure what.
Any help is appreciated!
30-Apr-2024 13:15:14.958 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [ViewerFilter]
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Filter (org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @5bd82fed; jakarta.servlet.Filter is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @76a3e297)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4557)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1949)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)


Use Tomcat 9. Hint: ViewerFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter, not jakarta.servlet.Filter. Also, please check [help/on-topic]: This question is not programming-related, thus off-topic.

I was afraid of that. I figured since BIRT now supported Java 17 they would have updated all their references to 'javax' but I guess not.  And thanks for the tip about non programming questions, I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

As Olaf Kock mentioned, BIRT's class 'ViewFilter' implements javax.servlet.Filter, not jakarta.servlet.Filter.
BIRT documentation says it supports Java 17, but it looks like that does not apply to the Viewer at this time.

Java17 has nothing to do with the version of the servlet spec (javax.servlet vs jakarta.servlet)
